# ColumnConstraints.setPercentWidth() not working when using array

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using GridPane for my JavaFX layout, and I always use width percentages  for ColumnConstraints, but in one specific case it seems it does not work: when I set the width percentage of a ColumnConstraints inside an array.

My code:

```
ColumnConstraints[] myColumns = Factory.createColumns(3);
myColumns[0].setPercentWidth(35);
myColumns[1].setPercentWidth(12);
myColumns[2].setPercentWidth(53);
devicePane.getColumnConstraints().setAll(myColumns);
```

The array comes from my utility method for column creation using equally divided sizes:

```
public static final ColumnConstraints[] createColumns(int count) {

    ColumnConstraints[] columns = new ColumnConstraints[count];

    ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints(1, 10, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    column.setPercentWidth(100/count);
    column.setFillWidth(true);
    column.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
    column.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        columns[i] = column;

    }

    return columns;

}
```

Result:
[Columns with old width percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZz09.png)

But the expected is:
[Columns with right width percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUooE.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just creating a single `ColumnConstraints` object. This makes it impossible to assign different values to the `percentWidth` property. You need to create seperate objects for this purpose:

```
public static final ColumnConstraints[] createColumns(int count) {
    ColumnConstraints[] columns = new ColumnConstraints[count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ColumnConstraints column = new ColumnConstraints(1, 10, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        column.setPercentWidth(100/count); // do we still need this?
        column.setFillWidth(true);
        column.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        column.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        columns[i] = column;
    }

    return columns;
}
```

Comment: So even if I assign the object to different positions in the array and I set the attributes of one of them, are all of them affected?

Comment: `ColumnConstraints` objects can be used multiple times without any issue. There's one "set of property data" per object though. If you use the same object multiple times, all those columns will be set up with the same properties. If you want to assign different properties to each column, you need one "set of data" ***per column***, i.e. each column needs a seperate instance of `ColumnConstraints`. Otherwise all column properties for all columns end up with the values last assigned to "one of" them.